# How do I repair apt-get install after mixed install with rpm?

Tags: apt, 16.04, jre, rpm

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS Desktop, but I followed the instructions for installing Oracle Java Runtime for the rpm packaged manager.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/linux_jre.html#CFHBHAGI

```
rpm -ivh jre-8uversion-linux-x64.rpm
```

It failed to install and I just gave up on it.  However, now when I use `sudo apt-get upgrade` I get a slew of errors.

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up jre1.8.0-101 (1.8.0101-1) ...
Unpacking JAR files...
        plugin.jar...
Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jre1.8.0_101/lib/plugin.pack
        javaws.jar...
Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jre1.8.0_101/lib/javaws.pack
        deploy.jar...
Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jre1.8.0_101/lib/deploy.pack
        rt.jar...
Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jre1.8.0_101/lib/rt.pack
        jsse.jar...
Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jre1.8.0_101/lib/jsse.pack
        charsets.jar...
Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jre1.8.0_101/lib/charsets.pack
        localedata.jar...
Error: Could not open input file: /usr/java/jre1.8.0_101/lib/ext/localedata.pack
/var/lib/dpkg/info/jre1.8.0-101.postinst: line 641: /usr/sbin/alternatives: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package jre1.8.0-101 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 jre1.8.0-101
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
$
```

How do I undo this process and fix up the apt-get system?  Any explanation on why to not mix rpm with apt-get most welcome.

Comment: Why mix them? They are different, if they were same they will be 1

Comment: @Anwar Firstly, I'm new to Ubuntu.  I had tried to run another package which wanted Oracle's JRE.  I blindly followed the instructions on their website.  Ubuntu command line told me to use Alien to convert to a .deb package first, so that's why I did it.

Answer (score 0):

try running

```
   $ sudo apt-get clean
   $ sudo apt-get update
   $ sudo apt-get -y upgrade
```

after running these commands restart your system.
If you get an error in updating or upgrading try to repair your source.list file in /etc/apt/sources.list as:
You can use this trick. Open a terminal ( Pressing Ctrl+Alt+T ) and do these

```
> Remove the corrupted one

  $ sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list

> Open software-properties-gtk

  $ sudo software-properties-gtk
```

This will open software-properties-gtk and a new sources.list will be created automatically.

```
Then change the server to US or to any other server of your choice. You must enable repositories from the new dialog in order to create new sources.list.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer my own question as I found *one* way to apparently fix this.

I created a dummy `/usr/sbin/alternatives` file:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Do nothing"
```

Then `sudo chmod +x /usr/sbin/alternatives`.

Next, I put something in the `/usr/java/` directory using `sudo touch /usr/java/something.txt`.

When I ran `sudo apt-get purge jre1.8.0-101` it completed without errors or warnings.  I did a reboot at this point.  After rebooting I removed the two files above.

Now my system appears to be back to the state it was before I did the rpm install.